# How to hook into the delete event for a resource in laravel nova?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-nova

I have one query, I want to delete the image from the server when particular resource get deleted from Nova.

can anyone suggest me is there any way to override delete method for the resource.

**EDIT:  How to hook into the delete event for a resource in laravel nova?**

> Note: I know we can do using observer. but I am looking for another
>   way.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? It looks like the accepted answer has nothing to do with Nova.

Comment: its hook which I used to set in model.... if you implement below solution it will work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to hook into laravel nova's delete resource event, you don't have a builtin way. But the parent model's have a delete method, you can override it and do extra work there

```php
    //app/ParentModel.php

    public function delete() {
       /* add your extra logic for deleted model */

       parent::delete();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use boot in your model like this:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    self::deleted(function ($model) {
        parent::remove($model, self::$index);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used [Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers) and deleted function [Nova Resource Events](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/#resource-events) and works fine

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `afterDelete` method on the resource.

See the `HasLifecycleMethods` trait on the Nova `Resource`.

```php
/**
 * Register a callback to be called after the resource is deleted.
 *
 * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest  $request
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
 * @return void
 */
public static function afterDelete(NovaRequest $request, Model $model)
{
    //
}
```